# String literals support in LuaJIT's C parser

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

On the official [LuaJIT website](https://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html) one can read the following:

> The C parser complies to the C99 language standard plus the following extensions:
>     - The '\e' escape in character and string literals.

This should mean that LuaJIT C parser supports string literals!

Let's try:

```lua
    ffi.cdef[[static const char * s = "foo";]]
    ffi.cdef[[static const char s[] = "foo";]]
    ffi.cdef[[static const char s[4] = "foo";]]
```

Unfortunately, none of the above works: the error `invalid C type` is raised on each `ffi.cdef` invocation.

Can you provide an example how to feed a string literal to the C parser integrated into LuaJIT?

**P.S.**
I should mention that I can successfully declare `int` and `char` variables the same way, but not strings.

```lua
ffi.cdef[[static const int k = 42;]]
print(ffi.C.k)  -->  42
```

Comment: "*none of the above works*" In what way does it not "work"?

Comment: @NicolBolas - runtime error

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get a runtime error when you compile the C statement, or when you try to access the variable? Is there any information on the nature of the runtime error? Provide an [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Minimal reproducible example is already in the question.  Did you try to run it in LuaJIT?